# Сортировка массива по цене

Tags: javascript

Есть массив. Его нужно отсортировать по возрастанию и убыванию при нажатии на кнопку и отобразить в id='shop'.

```
const products = [
    {
        id: '7df3f04b-0ee0-4a8a-bda8-e2931e68860d',
        title: 'MacBook Pro 16-inch',
        description: '2.3GHz 8-Core Processor<br>1TB Storage<br>AMD Radeon Pro 5500M',
        price: {
            value: 2799.00,
            currency: 'USD',
        },
        imageLink: 'https://www.apple.com/v/mac/home/am/images/overview/hero/macbook_pro_16__ni9nkbyq2dm6_large.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '69d8b82e-1bc6-45a7-bcb0-ba205c91b8bd',
        title: 'MacBook Pro 13-inch',
        description: '2.4GHz Quad-Core Processor with Turbo Boost up to 4.1GHz<br>256GB Storage<br>Touch Bar and Touch ID',
        price: {
            value: 1799.00,
            currency: 'USD',
        },
        imageLink: 'https://www.apple.com/v/mac/home/am/images/overview/hero/macbook_pro_16__ni9nkbyq2dm6_large.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '9c56a489-5581-4552-802a-6e56249b0056',
        title: 'Mac Pro',
        description: '3.5GHz 8‑core Intel Xeon W processor, Turbo Boost up to 4.0GHz<br>256GB Storage<br>Radeon Pro 580X with 8GB of GDDR5 memory',
        price: {
            value: 5999.00,
            currency: 'USD',
        },
        imageLink: 'https://www.apple.com/v/mac/home/am/images/overview/hero/mac_pro__bn92faz71k6a_large.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: 'e325ae53-ba9b-4b9e-b443-20db05f95c2e',
        title: 'MacBook Air',
        description: '2-core Intel Core i5 processor<br>1TB storage<br>12 hours battery life',
        price: {
            value: 1099.00,
            currency: 'USD',
        },
        imageLink: 'https://www.apple.com/v/mac/home/am/images/overview/compare/macbook_air__csdfieli984m_large.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '4f50005d-b422-4adf-b1f6-3b6551862500',
        title: 'iPhone 11 Pro Max',
        description: 'Midnight Green<br>521GB Storage<br>20 hours of video playback',
        price: {
            value: 1449.00,
            currency: 'USD',
        },
        imageLink: 'https://www.apple.com/v/iphone/home/af/images/overview/compare/compare_iphone_11_pro__fvqwhr4dkhiu_large.jpg'
    }
];
```

Мой код

```
<section class="container _indent1" id="shop"></section>
<button id="sort-asc" onclick="mySort()">Цена по возрастанию</button>
<button id="sort-desc" onclick="mySortDesc()">Цена по убыванию</button>
```

JS

```
const shop = document.getElementById('shop');

products.forEach(function (product) {
    let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.innerHTML = `<div class="card _indent1">
        <div class="wrap">
        <div class="img"><img src="${product.imageLink}" style="height:113px; width: 173px; " /></div>
        <div class="info">
        ${product.title} <br><br>
        ${product.description}
    </div>
    <div class="price_info">
        <p class="pr"><span class="dollar">${product.price.currency} </span>${product.price.value}</p>
    <input value="Add to Basket" onclick = "dawn(this)" type="button" class="bt1" id="demo">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>`

shop.appendChild(newDiv);

});

document.querySelector('#sort-asc').onClick = mySort;
document.querySelector('#sort-desc').onClick = mySortDesc;

function mySort() {
    products.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.price.value - b.price.value
    });
    console.log(products);
}

function mySortDesc() {
    products.sort(function(a, b){
        return b.price.value - a.price.value
    });
    console.log(products);
}
```

Comment: И в чем проблема?

Comment: с выводом на экран. В консоле отображается.

Comment: Что такое *выводом на экран*? Консоль находится не на экране у вас? Пожалуйста, не жалейте слов, распишите максимально подробно что вы хотите, что не получается. Сделайте это прямо в вопросе!